# updat a Variable by change the checked Items in checkedlistBox C'

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have two Forms the First Form has an Array Variable and in the seconf Form there is CheckedlistBox.

```
 public partial class FormDiagramm : Form{
 DiagramAuswählen DA= new DiagramAuswählen();
 int c =DA.i_wahl[0]
 int c1 =DA.i_wahl[1]
 int c2 =DA.i_wahl[2]
 int c3 =DA.i_wahl[3]}
```

how can I change the Value of i_wahl[0],i_wahl[1],i_wahl[2] and i_wahl[3].
by changing the checked Items in the checkedlist box

```
 public partial class DiagrammAuswählen : Form
{
    public int[] i_wahl = new int[4];

    public void CLB_Spannung_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
    {
     if(e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked)
        {
            dd();
        }
     }
     public void dd()
    {
        int index_1 = 0;
        i_wahl[0] = 0;
        i_wahl[1] = 1;
        i_wahl[2] = 2;
        i_wahl[3] = 3;
        for (int index = 0; index < 19; index++)
        {

            if (CLB_Spannung.GetItemCheckState(index) == CheckState.Checked)
            {
                i_wahl[index_1] = index;
                index_1++;
                if (index_1 > 3)
                {
                    goto End_Wahl;
                }
            }
        }
    End_Wahl:;
    }
```

Comment: I think I'd skip the checked listbox and use a two column DataGridView bound to a list of objects that had a bool and a text property

Comment: How could I do this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How could I do this??

Make a new project with two forms. Form1 shall have 1 button. Form2 shall have 1 datagridview

#### Form1.cs

```
namespace Whatever
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var ps = new List<Person>()
            {
                new Person(){ Active = true, FirstName = "John" },
                new Person(){ Active = false, FirstName = "Jane" },
            };

            new Form2(ps).ShowDialog();

            foreach (var p in ps)
                MessageBox.Show($"{p.FirstName} is {p.Active}");
        }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public bool Active { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

#### Form2.cs

```
namespace WinFormsApp472
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2(List<Person> x)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            dataGridView1.DataSource = x;
        }
    }
}
```

I would put some words of explanation in, but there isn't really a lot to explain; Form2 accepts list via constructor, binds it to grid. Grid can be used to alter choices. Upon close, MessageBoxes prove Form1 has altered values

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]